# Can't change to alphabetical numbering in footnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I am writing an article.
I want alphabets to appear as bullets for the footnotes. So I am using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\title{{The title of the paper}}
\author{First Author\footnote{Details of first author},
Second Author\footnote{Details of second author},
Third Author\footnote{Details of third author}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main text goes here
\end{document}
```

But the footnotes it returns are always symbols i.e. "asterisk" "Dagger" "DDagger"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Without any additional information it is near to impossible to help you ;-) please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Are you maybe loading a package that defines footnote markers to use symbols rather than numbers?

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate a MWE.  Having information spread over the comments is not very useful.

Comment: Thanks...

I have built an MWE. But dont know how to put it here in the proper format for convenient viewing

Comment: @RehanJamshed I've done that for you. It's easy: select the code and click the `{}` button or press `CTRL`+`K` (this will indent all lines by 4 spaces which marks code as such in markdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code snippet after `\documentclass`

```
    \makeatletter
    \let\@fnsymbol\@alph
    \makeatother
```

Use `@Alph` for capital letters, `@arabic`for numbers.

**Edit**: Following the OP's request

> If I add another {\footnote{Corresponding Author}} that just makes it : a,b,c,d and what I want is : Asterisk, a, b, c

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@fnsymbol}[1]{\ifcase#1\or*\else\@arabic{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\fi}
\makeatother
\title{{The title of the paper}}
\author{First Author\thanks{Corresponding Author} \thanks{Details of
first author} \and
Second Author\thanks{Details of second author} \and
Third Author\thanks{Details of third author}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main text goes here
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can also have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\author[1]{First Author\thanks{Corresponding Author}}
\author[2]{Second Author}
\author[1]{Third Author}
\affil[1]{abc, XYZ University}
\affil[2]{xyz, ABC University}
\title{Common title}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Main problem is solved.

Next I want it to put an Asterisk for the "First Author" as  "Corresponding Author" . If I add another {\footnote{Corresponding Author}} that just makes it :

a,b,c,d  

and what I want is :

Asterisk, a, b, c

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your needs. You can play around with them to get different styles and choose what you want. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Footnotes in the title and author information are assigned symbols as a choice of the `article` class.

The definition of `\maketitle` in the class redefines `\footnotes` to be `\thanks` (this is not really important), but also does

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}
```

and this is what you'd like to fix.

In the code below I'll add only the necessary packages to keep it minimal and more usable by other readers. Also the printout uses a reduced text height in order to avoid large blank space.

### First attempt

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}
  {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\alph{footnote}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\title{{The title of the paper}}
\author{First Author\footnote{Details of first author},
Second Author\footnote{Details of second author},
Third Author\footnote{Details of third author}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Main text goes here

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second attempt

The above printout shows a defect: the footnote marks are above the commas and too near to the following name. We can fix also this aspect with another patch.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}
  {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\alph{footnote}}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}
  {\def\@makefnmark{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\title{{The title of the paper}}
\author{First Author\footnote{Details of first author},
Second Author\footnote{Details of second author},
Third Author\footnote{Details of third author}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Main text goes here

\end{document}
```

[image]